# Adding a column of type enum to datatable column

Tags: c#, datatable

Given:

```
namespace VolumeProfileStateEntity
{
    public enum VolumeProfileState
    {
        AboveHigh,
        AboveValue,
        AtOrNearValue,
        BelowValue,
        BelowLow
    }
}
```

I want to add a `column` of type `VolumeProfileState`:

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable("State");
```

Adding `columns` to the `DataTable` is fine until I try to add a column of type `VolumeProfileState`:

```
// Add columns to the DataTable.
var dc1 = dt1.Columns.Add("TimeFrame",
            System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
dc1.ReadOnly = true;

dt1.Columns.Add("Hi",
         System.Type.GetType("System.Double"));
dt1.Columns.Add("Low",
        System.Type.GetType("System.Double"));
dt1.Columns.Add("Middle",
        System.Type.GetType("System.Double"));
dt1.Columns.Add("State",             
        System.Type.GetType("VolumeProfileStateEntity.VolumeProfileState"));

Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentNullException' in System.Data.dll
```

I know I can make the column of type

```
System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
```

but then I have problems when entering data because `Int32` is not `IConvertible` to `enum` types AFAIK.

Am I doing something wrong, or is it only possible to add column types of `System.X` and not `enums`?

Comment: What is the compiler or run-time error that it throws?

Comment: As you've figured out, you can't just add an Enum as it is to a DataTable, you were correct in terms of you need to store underlying type of the enum (`Int32`) but also in another column can store the text value for visibility.

Comment: If you use `DataBinding` and a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` the combo column can use the enum names as the DisplayMember and the enum value as ValueMember to be stored in the DataTable.

Answer (score 1):

you should use a database column as int, then cast the value to an enum when retrieving it. You could also do the column as a string then cast to an enum when retrieving it. but int storage is smaller.